# DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator throwing NPE when groupRoleAttribute is also part of the groupSearchFilter

Tags: spring, ldap

Been working on an implementation in LDAP for authentication and loading roles. I have it working fine apart form in one case when I want to filter the result based on a particular role prefix.

Take the below example:

```
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch filterSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(baseDn, cn={0}", connection);

        binder = new BindAuthenticator(connection);
        binder.setUserSearch(filterSearch);
        binder.afterPropertiesSet();

        populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(connection, searchBase);
        populator.setGroupSearchFilter("(uniqueMember={0})");
        populator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        populator.setRolePrefix("");
```

The above example works fine and I am returned all the cn attribute values of the associated groups of a user. The issue arises if I want to filter the specific groups by prefix only including the ones required. With the following example:

```
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch filterSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(baseDn, cn={0}", connection);

        binder = new BindAuthenticator(connection);
        binder.setUserSearch(filterSearch);
        binder.afterPropertiesSet();

        populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(connection, searchBase);
        populator.setGroupSearchFilter("(cn=PREFIX*)(uniqueMember={0})");
        populator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        populator.setRolePrefix("");
```

When running the above code it looks up a user record and then looks up it's group membership. What happens though is the following NPE:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.lambda$new$0(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:184) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:270) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:228) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:213) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

If I remove the filter attribute "(cn=PREFIX*)" it all works fine. This is surely a bug in the Spring implementation? I traced it down the stack to SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues, The return value is supposed to contain the result and mapped attribute, but there is no mapped attribute in the scenario I describe above. If I debug I can see the results returned though but when an attempt is made tom extract the results based on the search attribute it throws the NPE.

Comment: The filter have 2 conditions but no operator. It should be `(&(cn=PREFIX*)(uniqueMember={0}))`

Comment: OMG! I'm an idiot. Thanks for spotting that!